# Looking for help solving an INSERT INTO error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a small sample query that creates a temp table with a `WITH` command, and then runs a `SELECT`.

I want to `INSERT INTO` another table the result of my `SELECT` statement, but I am getting an error

```sql
WITH testingINSERT AS 
(
    SELECT *  
    FROM Dashboard.test1
)
INSERT INTO Dashboard.test2 (number)
    SELECT * 
    FROM Dashboard.test1
```

The `WITH` statement in this case isn't really doing anything. However, I am trying to solve for the issue.

If I remove the INSERT line, the query runs fine

ERROR: Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT but got keyword INSERT at [6:1]

Tried to be more explicit as well, and see the same error.

```sql
WITH testingINSERT AS 
(
    SELECT *  
    FROM Dashboard.test1
)
INSERT INTO Dashboard.test2 (number)
    SELECT number 
    FROM Dashboard.test1
```

Tried this as well:

```sql
WITH testingINSERT AS 
(
    SELECT number  
    FROM Dashboard.test1
)
INSERT INTO Dashboard.test2 (number)
    SELECT number 
    FROM testingINSERT
```

If I removve that line INSERT INTO, everything works fine, however, I am trying to put the returned values into another table.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I do note that you are not referring to the CTE in your `insert`.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: I think you have to use testingINSERT into the second select statement.

Comment: Also suspect is that you've specified one column in your `INSERT`, and use `*` in your `SELECT`. Be explicit about what you're selecting.

Comment: If you define a CTE - then you must refer to that CTE in your following statement; try using `INSERT INTO Dashboard.test2 (number) SELECT (desiredColumn) FROM testingInsert`

Comment: You don't tell us the error.  But the `*` has a bad smell to it.  Is it only selecting one column?  If not that is your problem

Comment: Hi all thanks, Added the error and I am using BigQuery, added to thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Dashboard.test2 (number)
WITH testingINSERT AS 
(
    SELECT number  
    FROM Dashboard.test1
)
SELECT number 
FROM testingINSERT
```

Comment: Thanks you very much